# An unlikely but very bad event (technical word)

Tags: single-word-requests, technical, terminology

I'm looking for a word that describes an event or situation that is problematic but unusual. The word should indicate that something is theoretically possible, but so unlikely that you could ignore it. Example:

> Physicists laugh at the [unlikely but bad] possibility that the large hadron collider creates a black hole that engulfs the planet.

There are many words in the English language that relate to things that cause harm with varying shades of meaning: *pernicious*  events are harmful but subtle, *maleficent* characters spread destruction using tools of magic, and an *inimical* situation both harms and frustrates.

In technical fields, harmful but unlikely events tend to form the core areas of concern—the LHC is a perfect example.  It seems rather likely that there is a word, perhaps drawn from  technical jargon, that succinctly captures this idea.

EDIT: Added additional background, specified technical nature of question, and asked for jargon.

Comment: I regretfully agree that due to desirability being uncorrelated with eventuality, you'll need a necessary modifier to be accurate as opposed to elegant.

Comment: You want a single word that describes _improbable calamity_? Good luck with that one. I'm curious about why you believe such a word even exists; after all, we could take any word pair, and ask for single words that convey the meanings of both words, like _remarkable recurrence_ (something that happens regularly yet remains tirelessly inspiring), or _battlefield miracle_ (something paranormal event that happens amidst an armed conflict).

Comment: @J.R. On occasion, you can find just the right word.  For example, something pernicious is harmful but subtle.  Harmful but unlikely doesn't seem like much of a stretch.

Comment: @Mike - Fair enough. I suggest you add that to your question, though. Without that tidbit of information, it seems like you're on a quixotic quest for some ideal (but perhaps non-existant) word. With that information, it seems like you've given this a lot of thought, and there may be reasonable hope that the word exists.

Comment: This question, as unlikely as it may be, is a duplicate. Take a look at this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74741/opposite-of-miracle @J.R. I like hay stacks and needles ;)

Comment: @TsSkTo Yes it's close (especially before the edit), but perhaps we should keep it from "repeat" since I'm looking for a technical slant, not something divine. I've updated the title to reflect this.

Comment: I think you're looking for [MCA or DBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_basis_accident).

Comment: The problem here is that the answers to that question answer this question. `Words like "catastrophe" and "calamity" seem too general, since I'd like to express the exceptional unlikelihood of the event (or events)` sounds exactly like your question. I was going to say "Cataclysm", but that's before I found your doppelganger

Comment: @RegDwighт If we allow TLAs, anything is possible :)  Another that I just ran across is a [black swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory).  I quite like that.

Comment: How about *negligible*?

Comment: @Jim Negligible is unlikely, but not necessarily bad. "I've a negligible amount of money," for example

Comment: @Mike, agreed, however in most cases it is clear from context whether the thing you are discussing is good or bad-  Take your example, "Physicists laugh at the *negligible* possibility that the large hadron collider creates a black hole that engulfs the planet."   In that sentence *negligible* works quite well, and no further qualification is necessary.  Also, *black swan* is two words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One phrase that's gaining widespread adoption is [*black swan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory) or *black swan event*. This refers to unlikely but potentially catastrophic events, especially ones where the risk is under appreciated. From Wikipedia:

> The **black swan theory** or **theory of black swan events** is a metaphor that describes an event that comes as a surprise, has a major effect, and is often inappropriately rationalized after the fact with the benefit of hindsight.
>
> … the "black swan theory" refers only to unexpected events of large magnitude and consequence and their dominant role in history. Such events, considered extreme outliers, collectively play vastly larger roles than regular occurrences
> …
> Black swan events were introduced by Nassim Nicholas Taleb in his 2001 book Fooled By Randomness, which concerned financial events. His 2007 book The Black Swan extended the metaphor to events outside of financial markets. Taleb regards almost all major scientific discoveries, historical events, and artistic accomplishments as "black swans"—undirected and unpredicted. He gives the rise of the Internet, the personal computer, World War I, dissolution of the Soviet Union, and the September 2001 attacks as examples of black swan events.

In the comments above, @RegDwighт suggests the acronyms [*MCA* and *DBA*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_basis_accident), which stand for the synonymous *maximum credible accident* and *design basis accident*, refer to unlikely events that are expected to occur frequently enough that engineers must design around them.

Recent events clearly illustrate the difference between a black swan and an MCA.

> The tsunami far exceeded the MCA determined by the nuclear regulator, setting the stage for the black swan meltdown at Fukushima.

EDIT: Opened answer up to community wiki, since I don't want to have to accept my own answer.

Comment: @user814064 But, by definition, they often *are* overlooked. If they weren't, they would just be DBAs.

Comment: I never noticed you were the original questioner. I thought about and rejected Black Swan but I did upvote your answer.

Comment: We may have to call them *Black Swan **events***, not *Black Swans*.

Comment: @Kris While most authors append *events* to *black swan*, I think that the metaphor works better without it. Also, no caps; it doesn't come from the movie title.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a *fluke*, although after checking some dictionaries I see they associate it only with good events (I don't).

Also a *freak* occurrence.

Comment: I don't associate *fluke* with good things either, particularly when you consider that it also refers to a parasitic tapeworm.

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, I suggest, "worst case scenario" fits the bill quite nicely.  One strike against it, however, is that *more than occasionally* the worst case scenario comes to full fruition, not to mention at the worst possible time and in the worst possible way!

Nevertheless, this three-word phrase, though far from being technical or jargon-y, seems to encapsulate the phenomenon you describe.

Other than "worst case scenario," I suggest the following:

- apocalyptical
- eschatological (which given the anti-supernaturalistic tenor of our times may as well be a completely naturalistic theory or doctrine which informs a highly unlikely occurrence).
- low-probability, high-consequence events that become more important as the world becomes more interconnected (my paraphrase of an excerpt from Jonathan Baron's review of *Worst-Case Scenarios* by Cass R. Sunstein (see http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674032514&content=reviews).
- an improbabilistic forecast, prediction, surmise, inference, theory, explanation, heuristic, deduction, paradigm, or predication

Comment: +1 for "improbabilistic", although I'd never use such gymnastics in my writing.

Comment: A probabilistic forecast is one made based on statistics and the laws of probability (such as Bayes Theorem).  So wouldn't an improbabilistic forecast would have some other foundation, perhaps based on popular opinion or just a plain wild-ass-guess?  I suspect *improbable* is the term you're looking for.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  I guess I am thinking in philosophical terms.  If probabilism is the doctrine that although certainty is impossible, probability is a sufficient basis for belief and action, perhaps improbabilism means that even if uncertainty is possible, then improbability is not a sufficient basis for belief or action but is nevertheless worth the effort because even though something may be highly uncertain, it's still possible.  Then again, the foregoing may be pure rubbish and complete sophism.  You be the judge.

Answer (score 0):

***Unforseeables***

…was the word US Secretary of Defense Donald Rumsfeld used in this context in the execution of the plan for the attack, invasion, and occupation of Iraq.

It fits your specifications.

Comment: Oh, Rummy... I forgot about his *known known*, *known unknowns*, and *unknown unknowns* spectrum. An unforseeable fits the far end of the spectrum: Not just unknown it was unknown, but impossible to know that its unknown. But, alas, it does not mean unlikely (in fact, some would say the outcome was inevitable).

Answer (score 0):

[anomalous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anomalous) is probably the word

"*Physicists laugh at the anomalous possibility that the large hadron collider creates a black hole that engulfs the planet.*"