# A word for an evil miracle

Tags: word-choice

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74741/opposite-of-miracle) is about an unlikely event.
Just like a miracle can mean an act or manifestation of God or a saint, is there a word that means a similar thing, but done by e.g. Satan, or an evil deity?
Not necessarily an evil act in itself, but of demonic origin.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of the linked question? *[Act of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_of_God)*, one of the answers there, would be my suggestion, and generally refers to a bad thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mephistophelian](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mephistophelian) :

> - of demoniac nature. (Collins)

a [satanophany](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/satanophany):

> - a manifestation or incarnation of Satan; demonic possession (Collins)

also, probably,  an [apocalypse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/apocalypse) may convey he idea:

> - an event involving destruction or damage on an awesome or catastrophic scale. (ODO)

Answer (score 0):

"Evil miracle" sounds good to me, or you could intensify it by using "devilish" for "evil." user66974's examples are more literary, but seem good ideas.